# Longest most common substrings

Tags: algorithm, substring

My Problem is to find the most common substrings of a given string, which are the longest at the same time (not part of a longer substring) in an efficiently way (-> long strings)

Any ideas?

Comment: Lots but you should google or search stack overflow first

Comment: There isn't necessarily a longest string that is also a most common string. Example: my first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `Longest Common Substring` or `Longest Common Subsequence`? In any case, [Geek Viewpoint's Longest Common Subsequence](http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/dynamic_programming/lcs) should help you get the answer